# Como pegar o tempo de execução de um programa com shell script?

Tags: shell, shell-script

Estou criando um script básico no qual gostaria de pegar o  tempo de execução de um programa cada vez que ele é chamado no script.

```
#!/bin/bash

for i in {1..15}
do
 echo "Execucao $i"
 time ./meu_programa > resultados_nesse_arquivo.txt
done
```

Porém ao executar esse script, obtenho somente a saída padrão do meu programa, como posso obter resultado parecido como:

```
 Execucao X

 real    0m0,001s
 user    0m0,001s
 sys     0m0,000s
```

Comment: Eu não entendi bem, você quer registrar o **horário** em que ele inicia o processo ou a duração de **tempo** que o processo ficou sendo executado?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Isso acontece porque, por padrão, o **time** envia o resultado para o **stderr** ao invés de **stdout**.

Você só precisa redirecionar o output.

Exemplo:

```
#!/bin/bash

outfile="benchmark.txt"

for i in $(seq 1 15)
do
    echo "Execução: $i" >> $outfile
    echo "-----------------" >> $outfile
    (time cat arquivo.txt) >> $outfile 2>&1
    echo "" >> $outfile
done
```

Saída do arquivo:

```
Execução: 1
-----------------
teste1
teste2

real    0m0,003s
user    0m0,003s
sys     0m0,000s

Execução: 2
-----------------
teste1
teste2

real    0m0,003s
user    0m0,004s
sys     0m0,000s

Execução: 3
-----------------
teste1
teste2

real    0m0,003s
user    0m0,003s
sys     0m0,000s

...
```